# Method db.delete some rows?

Tags: android, sqlite, delete-row, sql-delete

In the table I have 4 fields (note1, note2, note3, Note4). I want to delete all the data in `note1` and `note2`. I have to add arguments to the method `db.delete`, but I have trouble.

```
public void delete() {
  SQLiteDatabase db= mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  db.delete(noteTable.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete always deletes entire rows.

To clear values in specific columns, use an update query, for example

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.putNull("note1");
cv.putNull("note2");
db.update(noteTable.TABLE_NAME, cv, null, null);
```